# passing vector as argument to Mata function

Tags: vector, arguments, stata

I would like to make a Stata program that will take some arguments and pass them to Mata, and one of the arguments should be vector. Simplified version:

```
clear
cap prog drop my1
program my1
    version 13
    syntax , it(int) beta(numlist)
    ... maybe to transform numlist to vector somehow?

    mata: mymata(`it',`beta')
end
mata: mata clear
mata:
void mymata(real scalar it,
            real vector beta)
{
            it
            beta
            beta'
}
end
mata: mata mosave mymata(), dir(PERSONAL) replace

my1 , it(1234) beta(1,2,3)
```

Is there any simple way of making this numlist into a vector and passing it into mata? I manage to do it with `args` instead of `syntax`, but then calling my program gets too messy since I have plenty of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
clear
cap prog drop my1
program my1
    version 13
    syntax , it(int) beta(numlist)
    local beta: subinstr local beta " " ", ", all


    mata: mymata(`it',(`beta'))
end
mata: mata clear
mata:
void mymata(real scalar it,
            real vector beta)
{
            it
            beta
            beta'
}
end

my1 , it(1234) beta(1 2 3)
```